# Simple iPhone image viewer howto

Tags: iphone, image

I need to develop simple image viewer, much like the default iPhone Photos application, but for images located on remote server. I don't have any point where to start as I don't have any experience yet with such task (how to make a slideshow and how to handle animations when user slides photos with his finger etc.)

Can you please point me to some source - docs, howtos or sample project of such a kind?

Comment: direct answers cannot be asked. Show as what efforts have you made and ask where you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you start with Joe Hewitt's [`three20`](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master/) library (introductory text [here](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/fb5c8bff32d74a9c311c2c0d2afbf2790a01e611/README.mdown)). In the TTCatalog sample app, you will find a photo browser and `three20` has been designed to easily use photos from remote servers.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: This worked great for me. I didn't want to use three20 because I just needed the image viewer and didn't want to maintain compatibility with all the other 320 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/1845/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend Titanium from [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com)?  I have worked in both xcode and titanium and for quick and dirty projects, titanium might work.  Lots of demos out there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  self.startX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
  //NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging");
  self.endX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;

  self.photoIdx = (int)self.startX / Normalize(1160);

  if (decelerate == FALSE)
  {
    int intoThePhoto = (int)self.photoScrollView.contentOffset.x % Normalize(1160);

    if (intoThePhoto < Normalize(1060/2))
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*self.photoIdx,0) animated:YES];
    else
      [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx+1),0) animated:YES];

  }

}

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

  if ((self.endX - self.startX) > 0 && self.photoIdx < ([self.photos count] -1))
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx+1),0) animated:YES];
  else if ((self.endX - self.startX) < 0 && self.photoIdx != 0)
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(Normalize(1160)*(self.photoIdx-1),0) animated:YES];
}
```